# While iterating through a dictionary inside a dictionary, more that one key gets modified despite the break statement

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pickle

I found this very weird bug that I can't understand.

First of all inside this function I unpickle:

```
tableOrders = pickle.load(open("\\\\VIERNES7-3\Documentos c\sharedTableOrders.p","rb"))
```

If I do `pprint(tableOrders)` I get:

```
{1: {'blink': False,
     'canceled': 'no',
     'orders': [{u'availability': u'si',
                 u'canceled': u'no',
                 u'category': u'Minutas',
                 u'kitchen': u'si',
                 u'name': u'Hamburguesa al Plato',
                 u'parilla': u'no',
                 u'price': 60,
                 u'ready': u'no'},
                {u'availability': u'si',
                 u'canceled': u'no',
                 u'category': u'Minutas',
                 u'kitchen': u'si',
                 u'name': u'Hamburguesa al Plato',
                 u'parilla': u'no',
                 u'price': 60,
                 u'ready': u'no'}]}}
```

Now I iterate thought table orders in this manner:

```
count = 0
for x in tableOrders[table]["orders"]:
    if (x["kitchen"] == "si" or x["category"] == "Bebidas") and x["ready"] == "no":
        print count 
        print int(event.widget.curselection()[0]) 
        if count == int(event.widget.curselection()[0]):
                x["ready"] = "si"
                event.widget.delete(int(event.widget.curselection()[0]))
                break
        count += 1
```

`int(event.widget.curselection()[0])` Will be the selected element of a listbox (it seems to work correctly).

The weird thing is that after I do this I have:

```
{1: {'blink': False,
     'canceled': 'no',
     'orders': [{u'availability': u'si',
                 u'canceled': u'no',
                 u'category': u'Minutas',
                 u'kitchen': u'si',
                 u'name': u'Hamburguesa al Plato',
                 u'parilla': u'no',
                 u'price': 60,
                 u'ready': u'si'},       <-------------- MARKED AS "si"
                {u'availability': u'si',
                 u'canceled': u'no',
                 u'category': u'Minutas',
                 u'kitchen': u'si',
                 u'name': u'Hamburguesa al Plato',
                 u'parilla': u'no',
                 u'price': 60,
                 u'ready': u'si'}]}}      <-------------- MARKED AS "si"
```

So both "ready" are marked as "si", and that is not what I was expecting since I had put a break there and it should only change the property "ready" if the count == the selected element.

I tried also clicking the third element of the listbox (that has an index of 2) and this is what I got from `print count` and `print int(event.widget.curselection()[0])`:

```
0
2
1
2
2
2
```

This is why I am confused since only when both are equal (2 == 2) the `x["ready"] = "si"` code should be executed.

I'm not sure where the problem is, I'm quite lost but maybe I understanding the looping or break incorrectly or I'm confusing how to handle the dictionary and `x["ready"] = "si"` does something other that what I was expecting it to do.

Just in case it wasn't clear, if I click the first element of the listbox (and thus `int(event.widget.curselection()[0])` is zero) I want the first element of the list to be x["ready"] == "si", if I click on the second one the second element of the list should have the value "ready" to "si" and so on.

<sub>I did not tag this question with gui because I have discarded the possibility that the problem is there to the best of my knowledge.</sub>

---

**EDIT:**

Since the problem seems to be when I'm using the pickle here is more relevant code:

```
l = []
for item in sorted(jMenu["menu"]["items"]):
        if item["category"] == selectedCategory:
            l.append(item)
pedido = l[int(widget.curselection()[0])]

##pedido is something like this:
##pedido = {u'category': u'Bebidas', u'price': 40, u'name': u'Coca Cola', u'availability': u'si'}
```

Then I do:

```
tableOrders.addFood(activeTable, pedido)
```

addFood is

```
def addFood(self, table, food):
    if not table in self.tableList.keys():
        self.tableList[table] = {"orders":[food], "blink": False, "canceled": "no"}#el canceled hay que sacarlo?
    else:
        self.tableList[table]["orders"].append(food)
```

And to pickle I do:

```
def dumpTableOrders(self):
        tableOrders = pickle.load(open("sharedTableOrders.p","rb"))
        #pprint(self.tableList)

        for food in sorted(self.tableList[activeTable]["orders"]):
            if not activeTable in tableOrders.keys():
                tableOrders[activeTable] = {"orders":[food], "blink": False, "canceled": "no"}#el canceled hay que sacarlo?
            else:
                tableOrders[activeTable]["orders"].append(food)

        self.tableList = {}
        #pprint(tableOrders)
        pickle.dump(tableOrders, open(r'sharedTableOrders.p',"wb"))
```

Comment: It looks like the 2 dictionnaries are the same object, maybe pickle merged them.

Comment: @CédricJulien hmm interesting, I'll have to go back to where I'm "pickeling" them and let you know. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Comment out the GUI stuff and see if you still get the same results.

Comment: @Shog9 I did and the results are the same unfortunately.

Comment: @CédricJulien good eye. When I do `tableOrders[table]["orders"][0] is tableOrders[table]["orders"][1]` it evaluates true. I'm still not sure how to solve it though. But at least now I know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the object you are pickling, surely there both objects are same e.g.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> d = {'name':'same'}
>>> ds = pickle.dumps([d,d])
>>> newd = pickle.loads(ds)
>>> newd[0]['name'] = 'different'
>>> newd
[{'name': 'different'}, {'name': 'different'}]
```

So look into the object you are picking and create copies there, alternative is to json dump it , that way you will not get same object again e.g.

```
>>> import json
>>> ds = json.dumps([d,d])
>>> newd = json.loads(ds)
>>> newd[0]['name'] = 'different'
>>> newd
[{u'name': 'different'}, {u'name': u'same'}]
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be exactly my problem but I didn't understand how you solve it. (What do you mean by "json dump it" What exactly should I dump?)

Comment: @Trufa, show us the code where you pickle the object, because problem is in that code, not in unpickling

Comment: I'm trying this, If it works, I'll build you a monument or something.

Comment: The only problem I'm not sure how to solve is that the pickle creates a file, this file is shared between other modules elsewhere. Is this possible with json? (I just saw that it is possible, I have to modify quite a lot of my code base though). I'll let you know in a minute.

Comment: I did quite a dirty hack, but it will have to work for now, I unpickled, converted it to json, and pickled back again. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Trufa, good that it is working, but long term you should look into why pickling save same object, and that may be correct behavior, if they after all are same object

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the advice, indeed it is a dirty solution and I will try to get to the root of the issue, thanks again!